# General error: -817 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -817 Metadata update statement is not allowed by the current database SQL dialect 1

Tags: php, sql, pdo, firebird, dialect

I have a problem (subject) with a SQL request (with Firebird). I'm using PHP and PDO but I don't know why it's not working.

I explain :

I have this request, working on FlameRobin, but not in PHP/PDO :

```sql
WITH MESCOORDONNEES AS ( 
    SELECT COS(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*'.$longitude.'/180) as LNG_COS, 
    SIN(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*'.$longitude.'/180) as LNG_SIN, 
    COS(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*'.$latitude.'/180) as LAT_COS, 
    SIN(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*'.$latitude.'/180) as LAT_SIN 
    FROM RDB$DATABASE 
)                                 
SELECT (6371*ACOS(LAT_COS*COS(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*C_LATITUDE/180)*LNG_COS*COS(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*C_LONGITUDE/180)+LAT_COS*LNG_SIN*COS(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*C_LATITUDE/180)*SIN(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*C_LONGITUDE/180)+LAT_SIN*SIN(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*C_LATITUDE/180))) as DISTANCE,
(c.C_FAMILLECONTACT||ascii_char(10)||ascii_char(13)||c.C_NOM) as C_NOM, c.* 
FROM CONTACTFICHE c, MESCOORDONNEES 
WHERE (C_LATITUDE is not null AND C_LATITUDE <> 0) 
AND (C_LONGITUDE is not null AND C_LONGITUDE <> 0)
AND (6371*ACOS(LAT_COS*COS(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*C_LATITUDE/180)*LNG_COS*COS(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*C_LONGITUDE/180)+LAT_COS*LNG_SIN*COS(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*C_LATITUDE/180)*SIN(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*C_LONGITUDE/180)+LAT_SIN*SIN(cast(3.14159265358979 as numeric(15,14))*C_LATITUDE/180))) <= 20
```

I tried to cast the pi value because I had an integer overflow.

Now I've this error:

```
General error: -817 
Dynamic SQL Error 
SQL error code = -817 
Metadata update statement is not allowed by the current database SQL dialect 1
```

if someone can explain me where is the problem and why.

Comment: what is real SQL dialect of your database? Dialect one is VERY outdated, actually there is no any reason to use databases other than dialect 3. http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/23218  Maybe you should specify it during connection - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ibase-connect.php  Also what is exact firebird version u use ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Specifying the dialect during connect is not enough, the database itself needs to be dialect 3 for full compatibility.

Comment: Could you please post the DDL of `CONTACTFICHE`, and also post the real query as executed as your current query seems to contains some PHP string parameters (which BTW is pretty dangerous as it can lead to SQL injection).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i think his DB itself is already dialect 3, but i am no sure so that was the first question of mine either